# Getting started with ROS and Kinect?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'd consider myself a pretty decent programmer, but I have no idea how to get started with ROS and Kinect. Does ROS have anything that makes it easier - For example, the ability to work with a 3d model of the world around the Kinect with programming? Right now, I just check the distance of the pixels on either side of the kinect and check if they're too close, which is rather crude. I'd much rather have an SDK or something to help, so I don't have to write all the code from scratch. My end goal is a robot where I can enter 2 points and have it get from point A to point B, avoiding any obstacles along the way. Ideally, point A and B could be miles apart(GPS)

So, how do I get started?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221710/getting-started-with-ros-and-kinect?/) by [laptopdude90](https://answers.ros.org/users/25202/laptopdude90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

download the openni package. or you can use windows kinect sdk (not in ros)

---

Originally posted by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) with karma: 150 on 2015-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [laptopdude90](https://answers.ros.org/users/25202/laptopdude90/) on 2015-11-30**:
And then what... That's incredibly vague, I don't even know what language to use.